# globally add the viewdata for particular controller in ASP.NET MVC web-application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to add some data for particular controller's all views.

the web-apps i have already have something who run first when a request come to server. if i make another something like

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            AddMemberLogin(); //Add the Member if he is logged in
            AddApprovalModeToViewData();
            ViewData["call3"] = //called func;
            ViewData["call2"] = //called func;
            ViewData["call1"] = //called func;
        }
```

if i make this in the controller that i found that they not run the function who already implemnted.

are their any way to run both function but this when request come to this controller i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an action filter:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["call3"] = ...
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["call2"] = ...
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData["call1"] = ...
    }
}
```

And then decorate your controller with this attribute:

```
[MyFilter]
public class BaseController: Controller {}
```